# How to allow all network public ip to access my database?

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I am trying to make my database available on the internet so I hosted my database on Google Cloud Platform. With their instructions, I am able to connect with my public IP address to access the remote database with my MySQL Workbench & make request with the database public IP address.

However, I realize that my IP could change because public IP is different on every network, which may mean my database is stuck on the local computer environment. What should I do to make the database available to all networks? I want thrid party users to use my api to get data from my remote database.

I am not sure putting the server on the internet is what a developer supposed to do, just trying to get things out of localhost but I am very confused. Please help me :)

> The problem (I think)
> [image]

> Public IP changes on different router, cutting off my database connection.
> [image]

Comment: 1) Never allow public access directly to a database service. 2) Allowing public IP access to your database will not solve the problem with connection issues when your IP address changes. Connections will be dropped and must reconnect. 3) The answer from @Imran is correct but you will partially solve one problem and potentially open pandora's box of future problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add all public-ip range into your **"Authorized networks"**

Add `0.0.0.0/0` as allowed CIDR for IPv4